# Correlating volume timeseries

Tags: time-series, correlation, lags

Consider the following graph:

[image: twitter and trading volume]

The red line (left axis) describes the trading volume of a certain stock. The blue line (right axis) describes the twitter message volume for that stock. For instance, on May 9 (05-09) about 1.100 million trades and 4.000 tweets were made.

I would like to calculate whether there is a correlation between the timeseries, either on the same day or with a lag - for instance: tweet volume correlates with trading volume one day later. I'm reading many articles who have made such analysis, for instance [Correlating Financial Time Series with Micro-Blogging Activity](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~vagelis/publications/wsdm2012-microblog-financial.pdf), but they do not describe how such an analysis is made in practical terms. The following is stated in the article:

[image]

However, I have very little experience with statistical analysis and don't know how to execute this on the series that I have. I use SPSS (also known as PASW) and my question is: what are the steps to take to make such an analysis from the point where I have a datafile underlying the above image? Is such a test a default feature (and what is it called) and/or how could I else execute it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: You can calculate them... you just can't compare them to critical values unless the two series are bi-variate normal

Comment: I've pasted raw data here: http://pastebin.com/tZajRae9 Is there a way to tell whether the series are bi-variate normal? I would really appreciate your comment.

Comment: After detecting the Outliers/Level shifts in each of the series the resultant adjusted series exhibited an AR(1) model. After incorporating not only the Outlier / level Shift adjustment AND the empirically identified AR (1) both noise series were free of auto-correlation (within structure). A cross-correlation of this two surrogate series indicated no substantive cross-correlation (among structure ) thus the number of tweets doesn't appear to help the prediction of volume.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two check for bivariate normality check three things:

1. check if first series of observations is marginally normal,
2. check if second series of observations is marginally normal,
3. regress on one the other  and check if residuals are normal.

To check normality at each of these steps, use normal q-q plots or you can use any normality hypothesis test.

Or alternatively you could check if every possible linear combination (real coefficients) of the two series is marginally normal. That would probably be difficult, though.

Edit: (6 years later)
I'll keep the above for posterity, but note I have a more recent answer to a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342335/testing-significance-of-correlation-between-time-series).

Comment: I have taken steps 1 and 2 and came up with the following boxplots: http://i.imgur.com/SDOTE.png Except for the 3 to 5 outlier observations, they look marginally normal. However, the Sig. value for the Shapiro-Wilk Test is 0.000, which would indicate a significant deviation from normality. With outliers removed, Shapiro Wilk Sig. is 0.201 for tweets and 0.004 for trades. Does this indicate no correlating is possible? Also, this is a timeseries - deleting outliers means deleting days within the researched timeframe. Is this an accepted practice?

Comment: I also made a p-p plot for step 3. Or at least, in my interpretation this is what I need (a linear regression with normal probability plot): http://i.imgur.com/EZ3Ic.png Any comments?

Comment: The marginal distributions don't look normal. There is a small section on inference on the wikipedia page [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient). Removing outliers is generally not a good idea. Maybe bootstrap a confidence interval.

Comment: The question is about correlation -- but the answer is about normality. The answer is upvoted multiple times and accepted. What am I missing here?..

Comment: A bivariate normal distribution is the simplest model that motivates/justifies using Pearson correlation.

Comment: This answer does not take into account of the time variables and threats the observations as independent. I don't think this is answering to the question

Comment: Yeah me neither. I'll delete it after we move the points over to @IrishStat. Current me is a little embarassed by it, actually

Answer (score 11):

The correlation coefficient between time series is useless. See [CORRELATION COEFFICIENT - Critical values for Testing Significance](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/dbs202/cat/stats/corr.html). This was first pointed out by U. Yule in 1926 [Yule, G.U, 1926, "Why do we sometimes get nonsense correlations between time series? A study in sampling and the nature of time series", Journal of the Royal Statistical Society 89, 1–64](http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~econ536/Papers/yule26.pdf). You might want to google "why do we get nonsense correlation" for more.

The reason for this is tests for correlation requite joint normality. Joint normality requires each series to be normal. Normality requires independence. To examine the relationship between time series please review Transfer Function Identification in any good time series book like [Time Series Analysis: Univariate and Multivariate Methods, by William W.S. Wei, David P. Reilly](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/Time-Series-Analysis/William-WS-Wei/e/9780201159110).

#### Challenge Answer

In terms of an answer to your challenge. It is well known, by a few ([Yule, G.U, 1926](http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~econ536/Papers/yule26.pdf)) that correlating two time series can be flawed particularly if either series is affected by pulses/level shifts/seasonal pulses and/or local time trends. That being the case I would take each of the series SEPARATELY and identify the ARIMA structure and any pulses/level shifts/seasonal pulses and/or local time trends that might apply and create an error process.

With two clean error processes, one for each of the two original series, I would compute the cross correlation which could then be used to measure the degree of association above and beyond the auto-correlative structure within each series. This solution is appropriately called the double pre-whitening approach.

See:

- [Model Identification in Dynamic Regression (Distributed Lag) Models](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1391593)
- [Analysis of fMRI Timeseries: Linear Time-Invariant Models, Event-related fMRI and Optimal Experimental Design](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/doc/books/hbf2/pdfs/Ch10.pdf) or
- [Time Series Analysis: Univariate and Multivariate Methods, by William W.S. Wei, David P. Reilly](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/Time-Series-Analysis/William-WS-Wei/e/9780201159110)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But are you then saying that by definition, a.o. the paper I referred to, has no value? Secondly, does this mean that by definition two series can never be correlated where cthe correlation has meaning?

Comment: The correlation can be computed as that is simple arithmetic. What can't be computed( easily) is the probability that the correlation is statistically significant. Think back to the first time you were introduced to the correlation coefficient. It was in the context of N independent samples where two characteristics/values were computed for each of the N independent samples and the joint density was bivariate normal.

Comment: Why does it require joint normality, and not just the same (symmetric?) distribution? i.e. wouldn't joint uniformity also work?

Comment: @NAUGHT101 . Critical values for the correlation coefficient are available under the assumption of joint-normality and undefined else wise.

Comment: @IrishStat Thank you for your editted answer. It is appreciated. For normality testing, please see http://i.imgur.com/SDOTE.png for q-q plots of the separate variables. After outliers are removed, a p-p plot, from what I understand which measures joint-normlaity, looks like this http://i.imgur.com/EZ3Ic.png Any comments?

Comment: @PrOno the plot of standardized residuals suggests a bell shaped distribution BUT it doesn't prove that the observations are independent of each other which is another requirement for normality

Comment: I think you should reconsider the statement *Normality requires independence*. IMHO, it does not make sense. Also, is it necessarily true that *tests for correlation requite joint normality*? Or is it just a small-sample requirement (before asymptotic results start to hold)? I suppose it is the latter.

Comment: @RichardHardy if a series has auto-regressive structure then the expected value changes thus it is not a constant thus the series is non-normal as one of the assumptions of the normal distribution is that the values are independent and identically distributed.

Comment: I understand what you mean (I actually have developed a similar explanation [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137462/how-to-determine-if-the-mean-of-1-time-series-is-significantly-greater-than-that/137647#137647)), and I was imprecise in my comment. But still, is joint normality needed asymptotically for the test statistic to follow the usual null distribution? Since correlation is well-defined on two distributions that are not necessarily normal, it would be nice to have a test that is as flexible.

Comment: Here I stand, I can do no other . Joint normality requires each series to be normal .