# Difference in mean between two periods in a time serie? What test to use?

Tags: time-series, anova, t-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a dataset of multiple experiments measured each hour, for 56 hours. Now I want to identify if there is a significant difference in the mean value between the time periods 1-2 hour and 50-57 hour (see image). What test is best to use here?

Another thing what do I need to use for checking significance of mean between the periods 5-8 and 11-17?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you will find my [answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137462/how-to-determine-if-the-mean-of-1-time-series-is-significantly-greater-than-that/137647#137647) to a similar question useful.