# Comparison of returns of two investment strategies. Can some kind of randomization help?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, finance, paired-data

My task is to compare the returns of two investment strategies using historical quarterly returns calculated from *S&P 500 Index* data.

Example: If I chose 10 year horizon of an investment, then for *strategy A* I have a time series of returns 1930q1-1940q1, 1930q2-1940q2 ... 2005q1-2015q1, and the same for *strategy B*. So I need to compare these two time series in order to determine **which strategy gives significantly higher returns**.

Both autocorrelation and non-stationarity are present.

I can't use paired t-test, since time series is not a random sample. There is significant autocorrelation of higher orders.

By differencing I just lose information about how high the returns were. And my goal is really just to say something like "based on historical data, returns from strategy A were significantly higher than returns from strategy B". I don't need to analyze trend of these series nor to make predictions.

I haven't found any solution to this problem. There were few similar questions on the internet but the asnwers recomended either to do something else than just pure comparison or to use t-test which I consider incorrect.

My idea is to use some kind of randomization. If I randomly chose say 30 values from the whole time series (the example above has 300 values), is it possible to consider these 30 values as a random sample? I assume that I could get rid of autocorrelation by this so to have justification to use t-test. I could repeat this 100 times and look how often I get significant difference.

Is my idea correct in any way? Or does anyone have any other idea? Thank you very much for reading and any suggestions.

Tom

Comment: Your question could be considered a duplicate of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137462/how-to-determine-if-the-mean-of-1-time-series-is-significantly-greater-than-that/252035#comment535114_252035), except for the randomization part. Does that thread help? Also, do you think the returns are nonstationary (you seem to say so)? If so, are you refering to the level (the conditional mean) or the volatility (the conditional variance)?

Comment: Thank you Richard, your answer really helped. I completely forgot about the HAC SE option. Yes, the returns are nonstationary. Yes, I was refering to the level (cond. mean) and you helped me with that. Next step would be comparing return/risk profile. I think that under homoscedasticity I can estimate risk by standard deviation and just create time series as return/SD values and repeat the procedure you mentioned.

The other thread also helped to clarify the issue. I am in the situation described there by having just one observation from each population, because the mean changes with time.

Comment: Under homoskedasticity, there is no need to transform the returns by dividing by the standard deviation. It would make sense under conditional heteroskedasticity, though. Hmm, so do you still have a question? I couldn't quite understand that from your comment.

Comment: So, what do you think? Does my answer solve your problem, or do you need further clarifications?

Comment: It does solve my problem. Thank you again. And you are right, dividing returns by constant would make no sense, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the difference between the two time series, $z_t:=y_t-x_t$ (where $x_t$ and $y_t$ are the two original series), and test whether $z_t$ has zero mean.

You could implement this by running a regression of $z_t$ on a constant and either (1) allowing the error to follow and ARMA process or (2) using heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation robust standard errors.

You would look at the statistical significance of the intercept of the model to see whether $z_t$ is statistically above or below zero, which corresponds to $y_t$ being above or below $x_t$.

This is simpler than randomization, and the problem of autocorrelation is handled in a more proper way (whereas I think it is not handled properly in randomization as you describe it).