# How to correct for multiple comparisons in time series data?

Tags: time-series, bootstrap, multiple-comparisons

I have two time series (length N) and I did a t-test to look at the difference between the two time series time point by time point. So I get N p-values from this. Obviously I need to correct for multiple comparisons but I'm wondering what's the best way to do it.

I think most people use FDR, but I wonder if that's too strict too, because (please correct me if I'm mistaken) it assumes independence among time points, which is probably not true in time series data. I'm thinking maybe some form of bootstrapping may help?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137462/how-to-determine-if-the-mean-of-1-time-series-is-significantly-greater-than-that/137647#137647) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279429/comparison-of-returns-of-two-investment-strategies-can-some-kind-of-randomizati/279447#279447). Let me know if it answers your question. Perhaps yours should be marked as duplicate of one of these.

Comment: Thanks Richard! I don't have an assumption about the functional form of my time series. But I'm still having difficulty understanding that we have to assume each time point is generated independently. Let's say in my original time series (of 100 points), I have a consecutive 20 time points that are significant (uncorrected). Now I take the time series but increase the bin size so that now every time point is the average of 20 original time points. Now I have a much less severe multiple comparisons problem - I only need to correct 5 comparisons instead of 100 comparisons.