# Measuring the change of an increment in time series

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation, estimation

Assume that two series ($x_1,\dotso,x_n$) and  ($y_1,\dotso,y_n$) are linearly correlated.

What is the connection between  $y_j-y_i$ and $x_j-x_i$ in terms of Pearson's $r$ and the variance of $x$ any $y$?

Comment: Do you mean *linear**ly*** correlated? Also, I think the title of the question could be improved. Also, is this a homework question? If so, please add a `self-stufy` tag and read its [Wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Edited, it;s not a homework question. any suggestion for the title?

Comment: I would have proposed one if I had a good candidate. But I think neither the old one nor the new one reflects accurately what you are asking about. Regarding the new one, the question is not about *measuring* the change; it is rather about statistical properties / relations of the changes in two correlated time series. Also, I think more information is needed to be able to answer the question. Nothing is said about the characteristics of the time series. I suppose $(x_1,...,x_n)$ are not i.i.d. If so, it matters what the dependence structure is.

Comment: Because arbitrary differences $y_j-y_i$ are not "increments" unless $j=i+1,$ please clarify what you are trying to ask.  When you do, try to give us some hints about the kind of "connection" that might interest you.

Answer (score 0):

As per Richard, your question is not clear. But I would like to share the following link

> [Correlating volume timeseries](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26842/correlating-volume-timeseries#comment50813_26842)

There is very high probability that above post will answer your question and very much similar to what you are trying to ask.

Also adding one more link to marry your understanding with above question

> http://astro.phys.au.dk/~hans/tidsserie/Notes_08.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If $Cov(x_i,y_i)=\sigma_{xy}$, then the covariance of differences is
$$Cov(y_j-y_i,x_j-x_i)=E[(y_j-y_i)(x_j-x_i)]-E[y_j-y_i]E[x_j-x_i]=$$
$$=2\sigma_{xy}-Cov(y_j,x_i)-Cov(y_i,x_j)$$

If you know the covariance of intertermporal cross-terms, then you can get the covariance of differences.